# Has anyone one resolved or worked around some of Issues with cell editing in JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We're using cell editing http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing with JqGrid. Our config as it relates to this is:

```
grid.jqGrid({
  ...
  bindKeys: { 
    onEnter: null, 
    onSpace: null, 
    scrollingRows : true
  },
  cellEdit : true,
  ...
});
```

We're not even trying to save just yet and while the navigation basics seems to work, there also seem to be a few issues with the editing portion:

1. If you have text areas in your cells, the ENTER key even with bind keys set to null for it seems to still trigger, so you cannot use enter in the text areas
2. It is 'cell editing' so why are non-editable cells included in the navigation between cells?
3. Again it's 'cell editing' so why are the editable cells not in edit mode when navigated to?

Has anyone been able to work around these and if so how? The whole 'enter' key thing in any of the edit modes to complete editing when there may be textareas in the cells seems odd.

Comment: If you use Guriddo jqGrid you can contact  [the support team here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4). The reason for this is that we see some improvements in our code, but in case you use free-jqGrid there is no sense to discus a unsupported product.

Comment: We have the full licensed paid version, but your link is to a forum with no obvious way to get an account. When we purchased the license. all we got was a download link to files we already had. No support info.

Comment: Another option is to write e-mail to the support team.